# Odin fonts unsharp, how to fix like Hera?

Tags: fonts, odin

Fonts are noticeably more unsharp on Odin on comparison to Hera. Se screenshots.
Is it possible to edit rendering settings on Odin?

Download images and view them at 100%:
[image: Odin screenshot]
[image: Hera screesnot]

Comment: This seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/issues/233) and [reported to the development team](https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/discussions/213) a couple of times. The issue seems to affect certain "standard definition" displays, which makes it a little difficult to track down the cause. That said, hopefully an update will be available soon to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's the font!
I changed to Open Sans as in Hera and the font is sharper again.

Comment: Could you please add more info on how to change fonts so that we can mark the question as solved?

Comment: The easiest way to change the the fonts is via pantheon-tweaks (https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks), in the fonts tab.

That said, using Open Sans didn't made huge difference for me. I think there is something wrong with the anti-aliasing settings in Odin. The Ubuntu fonts look slightly better than Open Sans, but it is still not as good as it could be.